# Filter multiple columns based on row values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a pandas dataframe structured as follow:

```
In[1]:  df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[10, 15, 13, 18, 0.6],
                           "B":[20, 12, 16, 24, 0.5],
                           "C":[23, 22, 26, 24, 0.4],
                           "D":[9, 12, 17, 24, 0.8 ]})

Out[1]: df 
        A       B       C       D
    0   10.0    20.0    23.0    9.0
    1   15.0    12.0    22.0    12.0
    2   13.0    16.0    26.0    17.0
    3   18.0    24.0    24.0    24.0
    4   0.6     0.5     0.4     0.8
```

From here my goal is to filter multiple columns based on the last row (index 4) values. More in detail i need to keep those columns that has a value < 0.06 in the last row. The output should be a df structured as follow:

```
     B       C       
0   20.0    23.0
1   12.0    22.0    
2   16.0    26.0    
3   24.0    24.0    
4   0.5     0.4
```

I'm trying this:

```
In[2]: df[(df[["A", "B", "C", "D"]] < 0.6)]
```

but i get the as follow:

```
Out[2]:    
       A   B    C   D
   0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
   1  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
   2  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
   3  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
   4  NaN   0.5 0.4 NaN
```

I even try:

```
df[(df[["A", "B", "C", "D"]] < 0.6).all(axis=0)]
```

but It gives me error, It doesn't work.

Is there anybody whom can help me?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `:` for return all rows by condition - compare last row by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.iloc[-1] < 0.6]
print (df1)
      B     C
0  20.0  23.0
1  12.0  22.0
2  16.0  26.0
3  24.0  24.0
4   0.5   0.4
```